# How to Change Django InMemoryField to PIL Image object?

Tags: django, python-imaging-library

Here Take a look at my code:

```
profile_picture = self.validated_data.get('profile_picture',False)
if profile_picture:
    pic = profile_picture.read()
```

Now, I want to crop the image if it's not in a particular resuloution; I want to convert the pic to a `PIL.Image.Image` object. How do I do that?